Streaming Stopped at `thread.run.requires_action` When Handling OpenAI Assistants Function Calling
I am working with OpenAI's function calling and handling streaming events using Node.js. I have set up an EventHandler class that extends EventEmitter to process events from an OpenAI assistant, and I am trying to handle the thread.run.requires_action event, which should trigger the calling of tools, processing their output, and submitting it back through streaming.
The issue arises when the event handling stops at thread.run.requires_action. Despite the tool outputs being processed, the flow does not seem to proceed further as expected, and I am not receiving the event in the controller.
Code Overview:
eventHandler.js

onEvent method: Listens for the event thread.run.requires_action and processes the required tool calls.
submitToolOutputs method: Submits the processed tool outputs using a stream and emits the event.
Issue: Although the streaming messages are printed in the console (process.stdout.write), the event is not emitted properly to continue the flow.

const EventEmitter = require('events');
const assistantController = require('./assistant.controller');

class EventHandler extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(client, project, dbURL, userID, projectID, res) {
        super();
        this.client = client;
        this.project = project;
        this.dbURL = dbURL;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.res = res;
    }

    async onEvent(event) {
        try {
            // Handle 'requires_action' events with tool_calls
            if (event.event === "thread.run.requires_action") {
                await this.handleRequiresAction(
                    event.data,
                    event.data.id,
                    event.data.thread_id,
                );
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error handling event:", error);
        }
    }

    async handleRequiresAction(data, runId, threadId) {
        try {
            let toolCalls = data.required_action.submit_tool_outputs.tool_calls;
            const toolOutputs = await Promise.all(toolCalls.map(toolCall => {
                return assistantController.processToolCalls(
                    toolCall,
                    this.project,
                    this.dbURL,
                    this.userID,
                    this.projectID
                );
            }));

            // Submit tool outputs
            await this.submitToolOutputs(toolOutputs, runId, threadId);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error processing required action:", error);
        }
    }

    async submitToolOutputs(toolOutputs, runId, threadId) {
        console.log("Submitting tool outputs");
        let finalMessage = '';
        try {
            const stream = this.client.beta.threads.runs.submitToolOutputsStream(
                threadId,
                runId,
                { tool_outputs: toolOutputs }
            );

            for await (const event of stream) {
                const message = event.data?.delta?.content[0]?.text?.value;
                process.stdout.write(message);  //<-- messages are getting printed in console
                this.emit("event", event);  //<-- But this line supposed to emit the event while accessing from controller file
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error submitting tool outputs:", error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = EventHandler;

controller.js

The EventHandler is instantiated and set up to listen for the "event" and handle it through the onEvent method.
Issue: The flow stops at thread.run.requires_action, and even though events are emitted inside submitToolOutputs, they don't seem to trigger further event handling in the controller.

const eventHandler = new EventHandler(openai, project, dbURL, userID, projectID);
eventHandler.on("event", eventHandler.onEvent.bind(eventHandler));

const stream = await openai.beta.threads.runs.createAndStream(
    thread,
    { assistant_id: assistant },
    eventHandler,
);

for await (const event of stream) {
    writeLog(`\n${event.event}  : ${event.data.id}`);
    eventHandler.emit("event", event);
    console.log(event.event);     // <-- Stopped at thread.run.requires_action and not proceeding further
}

Expected Behavior:

I expect the flow to continue and the tool outputs to be processed and submitted after handling the thread.run.requires_action event.
The event should be emitted and handled properly in the controller file.

Actual Behavior:

The event handling stops at thread.run.requires_action.
The tool outputs are processed, and messages are logged to the console, but the event is not emitted as expected.

Any insights into why the event isn't being handled further or how I can ensure that the event gets emitted and handled properly would be greatly appreciated!
